# Angular testing with Karma: after injecting controller, $controller() is undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I'm trying to set up testing for Angular with Karma and Jasmine. I've successfully installed and configured Karma, but I'm having trouble using angular-mocks. Below in aTest.spec.js I include a simple app, controller, and test spec to illustrate the problem. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

**My console output from Karma:**

```
Chrome 39.0.2171 (Mac OS X 10.8.5) ControllerForTest encountered a declaration exception FAILED
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Suite.<anonymous> (/Users/duncanmalashock/python_projects/scout/public/tests/unit/aTest.spec.js:19:20)
    at jasmineInterface.describe (/Users/duncanmalashock/python_projects/scout/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/boot.js:59:18)
    at /Users/duncanmalashock/python_projects/scout/public/tests/unit/aTest.spec.js:13:1
```

Chrome 39.0.2171 (Mac OS X 10.8.5): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) ERROR (0.004 secs / 0.002 secs)

**karma.conf.js:**

```
...
files: [
  'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js',
  'angular/vendor/angular-mocks.js',
  'tests/unit/*.spec.js'
],
...
```

**Controller:**

```
var testApp = angular.module('testApp', []);

testApp.controller('ControllerForTest', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.data = {
      a: 'foo',
      b: 'bar',
      c: 'baz'
    };
  }
]);
```

**aTest.spec.js:**

```
describe('ControllerForTest', function() {
  module('testApp');
  var $controller;
  inject(function(_$controller_) {
      $controller = _$controller_;
  });
  var controller = $controller('ControllerForTest');
  it('is defined', function() {
    expect($controller).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Module instantiation and service injection should happen in a `beforeEach`, not directly within a `describe` block. This will make them available to each of the following `it`s.

You also don't need to test `$controller`, that's an Angular service. Test your controller instead.

```
describe('ControllerForTest', function() {
  var $controller;
  var ControllerForTest;

  beforeEach(function() {
    module('testApp');

    inject(function(_$controller_) {
        $controller = _$controller_;
    });
  });

  it('is defined', function() {
    // This line can also be in the beforeEach.
    // Saves having to repetitively instantiate the controller.
    ControllerForTest = $controller('ControllerForTest');

    expect(ControllerForTest).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```